# Disabling column names in ps output

Tags: process, ps

How to format output of `ps -p` command?

To not show me something like this:

```
PID TTY                TIME CMD
```

but just PIDs.

I'm using Linux.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Use the `-o` option to select which columns are displayed. If you put `=` after the column name, the header line is suppressed.

```
ps -o pid= -p 1 23 456
ps -o pid= -o ppid= -o pgid= -o sid= -p 1 23 456
```

Comment: This answer has the benefit of being portable (supported by BSDs and [specified by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ps.html).

Answer (score 33):

Use the `--no-headers` to have the header line omitted.

Original output:

```
ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
27027 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
27071 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
```

With `--no-headers`:

```
ps --no-headers
27027 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
27072 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
```

Combining with `-p`:

```
ps -p 1 --no-headers
    1 ?        00:00:33 systemd
```

The `man` page for `ps` clearly documents this:

```
man ps

[snip]

 --no-headers
          Print no header line at all.  --no-heading is an alias for this option.
```

Comment: Doesnt work on macos. Naturall -____-

Comment: Indeed.  Wasn't expected to work on MacOS.  Question solely concerned Linux, as highlighted by the original poster.

Comment: np steve. Just documenting it here for future readers. The minor differences between BSD and Linux utils is highly irritating. sed is the worst

Comment: ok thx.  if you've any thoughts on how to include MacOS solution in answer I'll happily revise it!

Comment: i found that for particular column headers, putting a `=` after the column name to the `o` flag is a cross-platform way to do this. E.g., `ps -p ${pid} -o state=` will show the process state for `${pid}`, without the header. (Which is what the accepted answer states :) )

Comment: This solution will also not work in some of popular Docker images (e.g. Alpine based node:17.3.1-alpine3.14). The output is "ps: unrecognized option: no-headers"

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
ps -p <PIDs> --no-headers
```

to get a list of PIDs without the header.

Answer (score -1):

To get a list of only the PIDs use:

```
ps -eo pid
```

See also `man ps` section 'STANDARD FORMAT SPECIFIERS' for possible colums.

Personally I like the way Solaris shows the possible columns to use for the `-o` argument:

```
ps: option requires an argument -- o
usage: ps [ -aAdefHlcjLPyZ ] [ -o format ] [ -t termlist ]
        [ -u userlist ] [ -U userlist ] [ -G grouplist ]
        [ -p proclist ] [ -g pgrplist ] [ -s sidlist ] [ -z zonelist ] [-h lgrplist]
  'format' is one or more of:
        user ruser group rgroup uid ruid gid rgid pid ppid pgid sid taskid ctid
        pri opri pcpu pmem vsz rss osz nice class time etime stime zone zoneid
        f s c lwp nlwp psr tty addr wchan fname comm args projid project pset lgrp
```

Comment: This does not address the issue of removing the header that is displayed.

Comment: That's how you interpret 'just display PID'. Some can interpret this of just selecting one column, or as you apparently interpret: just values.